# Whack a mole game trouble

Tags: javascript

So im following a tutorial for creating a whack a mole game with javascript, and i have exactly the same code as what the tutorial shows, but when i check my console i get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined". This is my code

```
let moles = $('.mole')


let moleArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(moles)

let random;




function renderGame(){
    moleArr.forEach(curr=>{
    curr.classList.remove('mole-active')})

random=Math.floor(Math.random()+ moleArr.forEachlength)
    moleArr[random].classList.add('mole-active');
}
renderGame()
```

Comment: Can you paste the link to the tutorial?

Comment: @Tajni https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fgqvx9APc_Y.    
 Im around the 17 minute mark

Comment: Typo: `forEachlength` should be `length`

Comment: Try debugging the value of `random` and `moleArr` to see what value you are trying to access which is reportedly undefined.

Comment: @DylanLandry random is undefined, but the confusion to me is why was he able to do that in the video, just declare the variable ```let random;``` and it still worked for him?

Comment: @JoshSweeten If random is `undefined`, figure out what step of computed `random` leads to this value. I'm not sure why it would work for him and not you, it seems he does not have the same type you did previously.

Comment: Another typo: Should be * not + moleArr.length

Answer (score 3):

The error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined"` means you are trying to access the property `classList` of an undefined value. The value you are trying to access is `moleArr[random]`, which is undefined. We should either check the value of `moleArr` or the index `random`.

```js
random=Math.floor(Math.random()+ moleArr.forEachlength)
```

Should probably be

```js
random=Math.floor(Math.random()+ moleArr.length)
```

`moleArr.forEachlength` is probably undefined.

Comment: I fixed that typo but i still get the same error for some reason

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo: Should be `*` not `+ moleArr.length`

Previous:

$() is shorthand for a jQuery operation. Do you have jQuery imported? If you do, then no DOM elements match '.mole' so check your template.

Comment: Well i've used jquery on all my other projects and it seems to work fine, so i dont think it would be that, but just in case how would i check my VS code editor to be sure its imported?

Comment: I believe its imported. and im prettysure i have an element to match '.mole'. This is a snippet of the html ```<div class = 'grid'>
        <div class = 'row'>
            <div class = 'square'>
                <img src = 'molePic.jpg' class = 'mole' id = '1'>
             </div>
```

Comment: On your whack a mole page, type `$ === jQuery` in the console. If you get an error then it's not loaded, otherwise you should get true.

Comment: Yea i got true, hmmm

Comment: Looks like it was having the + symbol in front of moleArr.length instead of the * symbol. Thanks for the help!